# Ruby: target-less 'case', compared to 'if'

Tags: ruby

*(I have asked this question already [at Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6875925), but it didn't draw any answer, so I'm crossposting it now)*

From my understanding, the following pieces of code are equivalent under
Ruby 1.9 and higher:

```
# (1)
case
when x < y
  foo
when a > b
  bar
else
  baz
end

# (2)
if x < y
  foo
elsif a > b
  bar
else
  baz
end
```

So far I would have always used (2), out of a habit. Could someone think
of a particular reason, why either (1) or (2) is "better", or is it just
a matter of taste?

CLARIFICATION: Some users have objected, that this question would just be "opinion-based", and hence not suited to this forum. I therefore think that I did not make myself clear enough: I don't want to start a discussion on personal programming style. The reason why I brought up this topic is this:

I was surprised, that Ruby offered two very different syntaxes (target-less case, and if-elsif) for, as it seems to me, the exactly same purpose, in particular since the if-elsif syntax is the one virtually every programmer is familiar. I wouldn't even consider 'target-less if' as "syntactic sugar", because it doesn't allow me to express the programming logic more consisely then 'if-elsif'.

So I wonder in what situation I might want to use the 'target-less case' construct. Does it give a performance advantage? Is it different from if-elsif in some subtle way which I just don't notice?

ADDITIONAL FINDINGS regarding the implementation of target-less case:

Olivier Poulin has pointed out, that a target-less case statement would explicitly use the === operator against the value "true", which would cause a (tiny) perfomance penalty of the 'case' compared to 'if' (and one more reason why I don't see why someone might want to use it).

However, when checking the documentation of the case statement for Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 2.0, I found that they describe it differently, but both at least suggest that === might NOT be used in this case. In the case of [Ruby 1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-case):

> Case statements consist of an optional condition, which is in the position of an argument to case, and zero or more when clauses. The first when clause to match the condition (or to evaluate to Boolean truth, if the condition is null) “wins”

Here it says, that if the condition (i.e. what comes after 'case') is null (i.e. does not exist), the first 'when' clause which evaluates to true is the one being executed. No reference to === here.

In [Ruby 2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html), the wording is completely different:

> The case expression can be used in two ways. The most common way is to compare an object against multiple patterns. The patterns are matched using the +===+ method [.....]. The other way to use a case expression is like an if-elsif expression: [example of target-less case is given here].

It hence says that === is used in the "first" way (case with target), while the target-less case "is like" if-elsif. No mentioning of === here.

Comment: ++ for declaring your cross post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Midwire ran a few benchmarks and concluded that if/elsif is faster
>   than case because case “implicitly compares using the more expensive
>   === operator”.

[Here](http://www.daniellesucher.com/2013/07/ruby-case-versus-if/) is where I got this quote. It compares `if`/`elsif` statements to `case`.

It is very thorough and explores the differences in the instruction sequence, definitely will give you an idea on which is better.

The main thing i pulled from the post though, is that both if/else if and case have no **huge** differences, both can usually be used interchangeably.

Some major differences can present themselves depending on how many cases you have.

```
n = 1 (last clause matches)
if:           7.4821e-07
threequal_if: 1.6830500000000001e-06
case:         3.9176999999999997e-07

n = 15 (first clause matches)
if:           3.7357000000000003e-07
threequal_if: 5.0263e-07
case:         4.3348e-07
```

As you can see, if the last clause is matched,`if`/`elsif` runs **much** slower than case, while `if` the first clause is matched, it's the other way around.

This difference comes from the fact that `if`/`elsif` uses `branchunless`, while `case` uses `branchif` in their instruction sequences.

---

Here is a test I did on my own with a target-less `case` vs `if`/`elsif` statements (using "=="). The first time is `case`, while the second time is `if`/`elsif`.

First test, 5 `when` statements, 5 `if`/`elsif`, the first clause is true for both.

```
Time elapsed 0.052023 milliseconds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Time elapsed 0.031467999999999996 milliseconds
```

Second test, 5 `when` statements, 5 `if`/`elsif`, the last(5th) clause is true for both.

```
Time elapsed 0.001224 milliseconds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Time elapsed 0.028578 milliseconds
```

As you can see, just as we saw before, when the first clause is true, if/elsif perform better than case, while case has a **massive** performance advantage when the last clause is true.

**CONCLUSION**

Running more tests has shown that it probably comes down to probability. If you think the answer is going to come earlier in your list of clauses, use `if`/`elsif`, otherwise `case` seems to be faster.

The main thing that this has shown is that both `case` and `if`/`elsif` are equally efficient and that using one over the other comes down to probability and taste.

Comment: I've always found `case` to be faster when comparing to static values and `if` when applying arbitrary logic.

Comment: The `case (x)` form performs very well vs. the open-ended `case` with no argument. In benchmarks I've found `case(x)` vs. static values like `2` or `"2"` can outperform a Hash lookup. The more conditions you have, the slower an `if` equivalent of one of those will go.

Comment: @tadman very interesting. However, according to the post, When you use `case(x)` vs static values like `2`, it uses the expensive `===` operator ( `x===2` ) while if doesn't need to (unless you specifically tell it to) thus making case slower that `if/else if`.

Comment: I know it does, but there must be some internal optimizations going on otherwise the benchmark scores wouldn't be so good. [Here's a test where `case` prevails](https://gist.github.com/tadman/54445fba7b65d757635d) and `if` performs *extremely* poorly. This is doing straight integer comparisons, which seem very quick.

Comment: @tadman wow, very interesting. Could you look at your instruction sequence for me? Is it still `branchunless` vs `branchif`?

Comment: Hack around with it yourself to compare other things. I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82006/discussion-between-olivier-poulin-and-tadman).

Comment: @Olivier Poulin: The article which you quote uses 'case with target', not 'targetless case'. I don't see why the === should be used in 'targetless case'. You don't have a target against which to use it.

Comment: @user1934428 if you follow the links in the article that i quoted, they explain that the difference between a case with target and a targetless case is only that each `when` is compared to "true" to test its Boolean truth. In each case the expensive "===" is assumed to be called.

Comment: @Olivier Poulin: I have read again the article you linked to, and also followed the links in this article .... beat me, but I don't find the place where it would be explained that === is used in target-less case. However, I found something independently and put it at the end of my posting (under ADDITIONAL FINDINGS), which relates to your argument. Could you have a look at it and let me know what you think?

Comment: @user1934428 very interesting, i'll go and run some more tests and get back to you. Even if target-less case does _not_ use `===` , the second part of my answer might present some performance differences.

Comment: @user1934428 hey, so i did some more testing (on  target-less case). Just like the with target case, case take much longer when the answer is one of the first cases, while if takes longer when the answer is later. Look at my edited answer to see my test.